# compilation error in Scala - type mismatch

Tags: scala

This`s compile without problem :

```
class Tweet(val user: String, val text: String, val retweets: Int) { 
  override def toString: String = "User: " + user + "\n" + "Text: " + text + " [" + retweets + "]" 
}

var max: Tweet = elem
def most(cur: Tweet) {
  if (cur.retweets > max.retweets) max=cur
}
foreach(most( _ ))
```

But this not compile :

```
var max: Tweet = elem
foreach( if ( _.retweets > max.retweets) max=_ )
```

Why ?

I got this error:

```
Error:(157, 19) missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.retweets.$greater(max.retweets))
    foreach( if ( _.retweets > max.retweets) max=_ )

Error:(157, 14) type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: objsets.Tweet => Unit
    foreach( if ( _.retweets > max.retweets) max=_ )
```

Comment: what is a Tweet? is foreach a function defined by you?

Comment: `code`class Tweet(val user: String, val text: String, val retweets: Int) {
  override def toString: String =
    "User: " + user + "\n" +
      "Text: " + text + " [" + retweets + "]"
}

Comment: and what is the foreach function? because I can't find to which object is that line being applied: `foreach(most( _ ))`

Comment: @adamwy's answer explains what's going on, but in your case `foreach(most)` should work, with no underscores (Assuming your `foreach` is defined as `foreach(f : Tweet => Unit), like in the standard collections`

Comment: Code is part of Cursera progfun course, code is here: [link](http://alaska.epfl.ch/~dockermoocs/progfun1/objsets.zip)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for that, is that each underscore refers to the next argument, so for instance, if you have a function defined like this:

```scala
def foo(f: (Int, Int) => Int)
```

You can use anonymous function using exactly two underscores:

```scala
// Valid:
foo(_ + _)

// Invalid:
foo(_ + 1)
foo(_ + _ + _)
```

So in your example, if you want to reuse the argument in the closure given to `foreach` function, you must call it this way:

```scala
foreach(i => if (i.retweets > max.retweets) max = i)
```

Comment: Working! Thanks. I understand it now.

Comment: Although it's still the wrong thing to do.  `max = <your collection>.maxBy(_.retweets).retweets`